# Elasticsearch Aggregation - Return a list of array from documents found

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate-functions

I am querying a time series data using the aggregation functionality. The data to be queried is of categorical nature.
I use date histogram to first create buckets. From these generated buckets, I wish to extract actual values from the documents found, forming an array.

A workaround to the solution might be pushing hits object within the aggs object. Don't know how to do this either.

The query:

```
GET elastiflow-*/_search
{
  "size": 10000,
  "sort": [
    {
      "@timestamp": {
        "order": "desc",
        "unmapped_type":"boolean"
      }
    }
  ],
  "_source": {
    "includes": ["time", "data" ]
  }
  , "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "gte": "now-2d/d",
            "lte": "now"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  , "aggs": {
    "30secbuckets": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "time",
        "fixed_interval": "30s"
      }
      , "aggs": {
        "average": {
            "terms": {
            "field": "data"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`top_hits` metric](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregation:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "gte": "now-2d/d",
            "lte": "now"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "30secbuckets": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "time",
        "fixed_interval": "30s"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 100,
            "sort": [
              {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "order": "desc",
                  "unmapped_type": "boolean"
                }
              }
            ],
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "time",
                "data"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "average": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "data"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the response. 
I need the query to return all the hits and not just the top hits. How do I get that? Also, this query return key, _id and many such metadatas but I don't see it returning an array of the data found in the histogram generated buckets.

Comment: Each bucket returns the documents present in that bucket, the `_source` in `hits` are what you are looking for and you can increase the size if you need more data

Comment: The _source only returns time. data is not present.

Comment: That means `data` is not in the document you're seeing. `top_hits` really returns the exact same info as in the top level `hits.hits` structure